# Database Cache and Object Cache Difference?

Tags: cache

I am a bit confused here. Is there a difference between object and database caching ?

I am planning to only do object caching for my site.

Does object caching include database caching ?

Comment: Not an exact answer, but this question has a lot of good information: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74676/how-does-object-caching-work

Comment: that's very good information thanks ! I do believe that database caching is included in object caching based on what I read, but then again i could be wrong...