# Does WP get all post_meta on POST page?

Tags: posts, post-meta

If someone opens any post at the front-end, does it matter how many times I call `get_post_meta` function? I thought it could increase performance if I won't call that function 2-3 times instead of 20 calls on single post page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One call to `get_post_meta()` fetches all met keys and values for that post. All these values are then stored in the cache. The next call will just fetch the data from the cache. So you can safely call that function multiple times.

In details:

1. `get_post_meta()` calls `get_metadata('post', $post_id, $key, $single);`
2. `get_metadata()` checks the cache and calls `update_meta_cache()` if it doesn't find an existing cache.
3. `update_meta_cache()` fetches all entries with:

   ```
   "SELECT $column, meta_key, meta_value 
    FROM $table 
    WHERE $column IN ($id_list) 
    ORDER BY $id_column ASC"
   ```

The same is true for user meta values.

Comment: so, if i call `get_post_meta('smth');` then it also stored in cache all other keys (not only `smth`), right? wow, good.

Answer (score 2):

> ...I thought it could increase performance if I won't call that function 2-3 times instead of 20 calls on single post page

Together with the excellent answer from @toscho, I will just add one additional thing, based on my latest [digging](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226960/why-query-posts-isnt-marked-as-deprecated/248955#248955).

If you don't set it otherwise WordPress queries will prefetch post meta values for all the posts **the query** returns.

This means even before you call `get_post_meta();` the meta values are already in the WordPress cache.

Nacin, explained [this](http://wordpress.tv/2012/06/15/andrew-nacin-wp_query/) and you can refer the slide 34 in this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-portland-2011).

[image]

From this image, you may understand that typically WordPress prefetches the information for the metadata and also for the terms.

The conclusion is the same as from @toscho. You may call `get_post_meta();` whenever you need.

---

To get the basic details on how the caching looks, you also may check [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74676/how-does-object-caching-work/249358#249358).