# Widget - Store and update data

Tags: widgets, api

What is the best way to store data? Database, cache, etc?

I want to build a widget, which will show some data from API, but I don't want to call API every time, because of limits. I'd like to call API every 3 hours or once a day and store data from API and timestamp when API was called.

How to do it?

*Sorry, don't have a code to show. It's more theoretical question*

Comment: Sore it via transient, a WP core technic. Add also an object cache, so that you have more cache features from the server for the transients. This answer have more information https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74676/how-does-object-caching-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to look at using WordPress [Transients](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) as they can handle both the data and the timestamp/expiration.

You can also check out [The Deal with WordPress Transients](https://css-tricks.com/the-deal-with-wordpress-transients/) by CSS Tricks which has some good info as well.

Answer (score 1):

For such purposes[Transient API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API%20%27Transients%20API%27) is the right choice to use.

> **From Codex page:**
>
> Transient API offers a simple and standardized way of storing cached
> data in the database temporarily by giving it a custom name and a
> timeframe after which it will expire and be deleted.
>
> ...
>
> Also of note is that Transients are inherently sped up by caching
> plugins, where normal Options are not. A memcached plugin, for
> example, would make WordPress store transient values in fast memory
> instead of in the database. For this reason, transients should be used
> to store any data that is expected to expire, or which can expire at
> any time. Transients should also never be assumed to be in the
> database, since they may not be stored there at all.

### Example code

#### How to SET Transients

`set_transient( $transient, $value, $expiration );`

**$transient**

(string) Transient name. Expected to not be SQL-escaped. Must be 172 characters or fewer in length.

**$value**

(array|object) Data to save, either a regular variable or an array/object. The API will handle serialization of complex data for you.

**$expiration**

(integer) The maximum of seconds to keep the data before refreshing. Transients may expire before the $expiration (Due to External Object Caches, or database upgrades) but will never return their value past $expiration.

So for example to save the $special_query_results object for 12 hours you would do:

`set_transient( 'special_query_results', $special_query_results, 60*60*12 );`

#### How to GET transient

`get_transient( $transient );`

$transient the unique slug used while saving the transient with set_transient().

In our case we could fetch our special query results with:

`get_transient( 'special_query_results' );`

If the transient does not exist, or has expired, then `get_transient()` will return `false`. This should be checked using the identity operator (===) instead of the normal equality operator (==), because an integer value of zero (or other "empty"/"falsey" data) could be the data you're wanting to store. Because of this "false" value, transients should not be used to hold plain boolean values (true/false). Put them into an array or convert them to integers instead.

Example usage:

```
if ( false === ( $value = get_transient( 'value' ) ) ) {
     // this code runs when there is no valid transient set
}
```

The above code will get the transient and put it into `$value`. The code inside the if block only runs when there's not a valid transient for it to get. This is typically a method to re-generate the transient value through other means. Keep in mind that it's possible for a transient to not be available before it's normal expiration time.

### Complete Example

```
function wp1707_get_my_api_data ( $update = false ){
    // Checking if our transient is available.
    $my_api_data = get_transient( 'wp1707_my_api_data' );

    // Is transient data not available or do we want to force the update?
    if ( empty( $my_api_data ) || !$update) {

        // Get the data from API
        $my_api_data = call_to_my_api();
        // Now let's set that data as transient and store it for 3hours
        set_transient( 'wp1707_my_api_data', $my_api_data, 3 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    }

    // 
    return $my_api_data;
}
```

---

### Caveats when using Transients API

1. Transients are time bound but they may expire **before** the expiration time you set. **Always make sure to have fallback in your code.**
2. When caching plugins/mechanisms are used, transients are stored outside of database all together. **Never assume or expect transients to be *stored* inside database.**
3. Make sure that the slug that you use is unique. Generalized slugs such as `my_api_data` are poor design decision. It's best to pad the slugs with unique prefix/suffix such as `wp1707_wcf_my_api_data`. This is to ensure that any other poorly designed plugin/theme don't overwrite your transient data.
4. Transients API is not suitable for every scenario. Read this great post by Pressjitsu - [Don't Cache Everything with Transients](https://pressjitsu.com/blog/transient-cache-alternatives/%20%27Dont%20cache%20everything%20with%20Transients%27)
5. [This article by CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-deal-with-wordpress-transients/) has some great pointers on pros and cons with example code.