# Caching of SQL queries

Tags: options

Within one plugin file I have several calls to the same option in the database via get_option(). Does WordPress do a database query every time I use get_option()? Would it be better to get the option once and store it in a global variable?

Comment: [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/27720/4771) explains how options work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plugin options autoloading](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87734/plugin-options-autoloading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress will only do a database lookup the first time if the option hasn't been auto-loaded or already accessed prior. The performance hit is negligible, however if you're loading multiple separate options with a bunch of get_options instead of using the serialised option functionality, then the initial lookup * X number of separate option rows could potentially cause performance issues.

In your other question which is a duplicate of this one, I answer the question with an example of best practice code if you're concerned with get_option performance [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87734/plugin-options-autoloading).